# Django half filled forms

Tags: python, django, forms

How do i save a half filled form?

eg: User logs in and registers for a service. Remembers that some scanned docs are missing. Saves the form for completion at a later date. Comes back completes it and submits it.

Solutions I came up with

1. I can set the required field to False and save the half filled form to DB. But that defeats the purpose of required fields.
2. I can save the half filled data in a seperate table. Migrate to the actual table once validating passes.

However for something so simple does Django not already have inbuilt functionalities.
If I am missing some term here that I should be googling point me in the right direction.

Django 1.6
Python 2.7

Comment: There is a duscussion of this in Pro Django by Marty Alchin (Apress) on  page 128.

Comment: This seems promising. Will get back once Ive read it completely

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way to do this is to store the data posted and save it in the user session.

eg.

`form_state = request.POST.copy()
request.session['form_state'] = form_state`

Something similar is done by form form wizard (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/)

Comment: will this data be available after the user logs out?